# Possible to replicate couch database with illegal name

Tags: couchdb

I'm using this command to replicate a 100mb database

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate \
   -d '{"source": "http://example.com:5984/bad_name_with_underscore", "target": "good_name"}'
```

I cannot replicate, because CouchDB says the source database name contains illegal chars. *I can understand CouchDB folks discourage user to create bad database name, but reading from it is no harm.*

I'm not an admin of source CouchDB, so I tried to export database as JSON and then bulk put to new database. But I met `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Missing JSON list of 'docs'"}`. Although I have tried to modify the dump.json by changing the structure to `{"docs": [...]}`.

I'd like to know, is there any other way I can replicate this database with some underscore in name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by using a client - PouchDB. Here is the code.

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
const source = new PouchDB("http://example.com:5984/bad_name_with_underscore")
source.replicate.to("http://localhost:5984/good_name")
  .on('complete', console.log)
  .on('error', console.error)
```

This works pretty well, so I post this to share with you all.